# Really Strange OpenCart (Product Specials) + FireFox (Cache?) Issue

Tags: php, firefox, opencart

The following page usually shows a special "sale" price http://tinyurl.com/9ja5eu2 (I think it's deactivated right now).  As shown in the image, it fails to show the price on "some" computers and in "some" browsers (Firefox).

I logged in remotely to one of the erroneous computers and launched it up in Firefox and I watched it work correctly in IE but not work in Firefox.  I cleared the cache in Firefox and reloaded the page, but it still didn't show the sale price.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why the "special" price wouldn't show up in some computers in Firefox?  It works fine on my home and work computer in Firefox and all other browsers, just not on other people's computers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean the **Rewards Points: 0** ?

Comment: Exactly what is not showing that is supposed to be shown? Did you check the source code (DOM) if it is there? Maybe it's just a version of Firefox rendering something differently. I don't see how you would get different code back in some browsers and not others.

Comment: No, in OpenCart, when you assign a "sale price" or "special," it will cross out the "price" and put in a "sale price."  I did check the DOM but it isn't in the HTML at all.  It's definitely weird, so I thought it was the cache.  But, after clearing the cache, it still won't show in firefox but will show in IE (only on specific computers, none of my own computers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update open cart.  Something must have gotten corrupted or something...